# Pyinstaller failed to execute script on Windows

Tags: windows-10, pyinstaller

exe file not opening in windows 10. I saw this comment below on stacks and tried it
'Try to open command prompt and drag exe into it and press enter, that way you will catch the error (if there is any) and then update your question, more info == more help.'

This was what i got
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "balls.py", line 12, in 
pygame.error:
    Couldn't open screenshotlogo2.png
    [9536] Failed to execute script balls