# Pyintaller on Windows 10 "Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap"

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm a primary school teacher using python and pyinstaller (directly and also via "auto py to exe") to make a single executable on Windows 10 that receives USB serial strings and converts them to keyboard letter presses using pyserial and pynput. It's essentially a serial data logger with some extra features. This was successfull and easy until recently when, on the same laptop, I now get this error when trying to run the generated exe:

> Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap

I'm fairly sure I've done some major windows updates between then and now, but I was always running Windows 10.
If I use "--debug all" in pyinstaller the next errors that pop up when running the exe (after clicking "ok") are:

> 1. "Error: (Null)" then
> 2. "Traceback: (Null)"

The code runs totally error free when running from IDLE (of any python version). There're no icons, images or other files I'm referencing. I'm really new to python and I've spent the last few days going over all similar questions here and following their steps, and I'm beginning to lose hope: (apologies for the amount of detail below)

- I've tried dragging the exe into a cmd window to get any detail on the error as suggested here. [Pyinstaller failed to execute script on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482903/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-on-windows). But nothing appears besides the same error message boxes.
- Deleting various pyinstaller folders and a --clean start = no change
- Tried on another Windows 10 machine with fresh Python/Pyinstaller = no change
- Uninstalled and reinstalled to test various python/pyinstaller versions = no change
- Running pyinstaller on a simple gui script with some buttons/text it works just fine with NO errors
- In the warnings file generated there appeared to be alot of missing DLL's so following some advice I installed the Windows 10 SDK and added the following to the pyinstaller commands using "--paths"

1. C:/Windows/System32/downlevel
2. C:/Windows/SysWOW64/downlevel
3. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows Kits/10/ExtensionSDKs/Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug/10.0.19041.0/Redist/Debug/x64
4. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows Kits/10/ExtensionSDKs/Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug/10.0.19041.0/Redist/Debug/x86

The Microsoft SDK paths aren't exactly the same as in the advice, but the same ones do not exist on my system. This removed alot of warnings about missing DLLS, but no change in the errors. The warnings file lists these 'missing dlls':

> 1. missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional)
> 2. missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional)
> 3. missing module named ce - imported by os (conditional, optional)
> 4. missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), tarfile (optional), shutil (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)
> 5. missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional)
> 6. missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)
> 7. missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
> 8. excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
> 9. missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
> 10. missing module named grp - imported by tarfile (optional), shutil (optional)
> 11. missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), serial.serialposix (top-level), getpass (optional)
> 12. missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)
> 13. missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
> 14. missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
> 15. missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
> 16. missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
> 17. missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
> 18. runtime module named six.moves - imported by pynput._util (top-level)
> 19. missing module named StringIO - imported by six (conditional)
> 20. missing module named fcntl - imported by serial.serialposix (top-level)
> 21. missing module named 'System.IO' - imported by serial.serialcli (top-level)
> 22. missing module named System - imported by serial.serialcli (top-level)

If I try adding them via '--hidden-import' they sometimes do not appear in this list, but then new ones are added. Adding them using this method generally has little effect on them being present or not in the warnings file and they mostly get reported as not being able to be found in auto-py-to-exe's report.

If I make the exe 'console based' using --console then try running the exe's I get a really quick scrolling console window that I screen captured here, which shows a few more details about those missing modules. Mostly they are about the "modules not being found in PYZ" and then being "destroyed" or "removed"

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRrhC.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFMgq.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRRZt.png
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbFBC.png
5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxhdx.png
6. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO2JJ.png

Is there any further advice anyone can give me? Even though it's working via IDLE i'd like to distribute this as a stand alone exe to the computers in my classroom for my younger students to use when programming arduino's or Micro:Bit's. Just to make it clear, I'm a beginner at python, so you might need to explain things a bit simply for me. Thanks!

P.S Apologies for any wierd formatting here, this is my first question on stack exchange and I kept getting errors stopping me from posting in a nicer looking way.